# extract reports based on string detect in a column -R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract data for each product by detecting particular word in the comment column
using String detect

```
Product <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c","c")

Comments <-c("The product enrolled"," product created","The product reviewed"," probable sale","probable sale","failed"
            ,"The product enrolled"," probable","The product failed"," product failed"
            ,"The product enrolled"," probable","The product failed")
            
sales<- data.frame(Product,Comments)
```

I am trying to extract reports of all products before " probable" word in the comment as a data frame by using str_detect
and after probable as different data frame

Expected output

data frame1: before probable

```
Product             Comments
 a            The product enrolled
 a                product created
 a              The product reviewed
 b              The product enrolled
 c             The product enrolled
```

data frame2: probable

```
a             probable sale
a              probable sale
b             probable
c             probable
```

data frame 3: after probable

```
 b   The product failed
 c   The product failed
```

Comment: Try `sales %>% mutate(group = case_when(str_detect(Comments, 'enrolled|created|reviewed') ~ 1, str_detect(Comments, 'probable') ~ 2, str_detect(Comments, 'failed') ~ 3)) %>% group_split(group)`

Comment: By any chance we can extract the data from a column before particular comment @akrun

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` (and `grepl`, as it works just fine here):

```r
sales$isprobable <- grepl("probable", sales$Comments)

library(dplyr)
sales %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  filter(!cumany(isprobable)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 x 3
#   Product Comments               isprobable
#   <chr>   <chr>                  <lgl>     
# 1 a       "The product enrolled" FALSE     
# 2 a       " product created"     FALSE     
# 3 a       "The product reviewed" FALSE     
# 4 b       "The product enrolled" FALSE     
# 5 c       "The product enrolled" FALSE    
 
sales %>%
  filter(isprobable)
#   Product       Comments isprobable
# 1       a  probable sale       TRUE
# 2       a  probable sale       TRUE
# 3       b       probable       TRUE
# 4       c       probable       TRUE

sales %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  filter(!isprobable & lag(isprobable)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Product Comments           isprobable
#   <chr>   <chr>              <lgl>     
# 1 a       failed             FALSE     
# 2 b       The product failed FALSE     
# 3 c       The product failed FALSE
```

Comment: By any chance we can  extract the data from a column before particular comment -R@r2evans

Comment: I don't understand. Can you edit your question and provide a clear example with expected output?